# Canada: ETA pending hours after application

Tags: canada, eta

About 3 hours ago, I applied for ETAs for me and my daughter (both German citizen) via https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/eta/before-apply-eta.html. Her application got approved immediately, but I am still waiting for decision of my application. I am getting nervous because I already paid for our flight, and it is supposed to be in 2 days. Yes, I know I should have applied for ETA earlier, but this is not the issue now.

My questions are:

1. Is this sth. to be worried about? How likely it is for me to receive my ETA in time?
2. I am getting nervous and keep asking myself if I made any mistake in my application. Would it make sense to apply a second time, while the first one is still pending?

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, you may have to reschedule the flight. But I *think* you don't have to worry too much until a day has passed, 3 hours is too short to know anything and it is end of day in Canada. Perhaps you are just selected for a brief screening and someone needs to press a button, but perhaps your file is flagged for some other reason and they need to take a deeper look.

Comment: For 2 they may cause the processing to be even longer, but I would try it as last measure perhaps the night before your flight (or just before your ticket becomes non or less refundable/modifiable). Sometimes the system is just glitchy.